# List gets empty on button event

Tags: asp.net, arraylist, data-structures, collections, hashset

Every time when the button event fired my list gets empty and starts adding items from first index. It is not retaining the old items added on previous click. I am trying to store ids of some element in my list on every button clicked and inserting them into hashset to avoid duplication. kindly help me out with this

Here is my code.

```
 List<int> venues = new List<int>();
 HashSet<int> hashset = new HashSet<int>();


                id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());


                venues.Add(id);

                foreach (int item1 in venues)
                {



                    if (!hashset.Add(item1))
                    {
                        Response.Write("<script>alert('Duplicate Items');</script>");
                        break;
                    }

                    else
                    {

                        foreach (var items in venues)
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                            cmd.CommandText = "select * from Venues where VenueID = '" + items + "'";
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                            SqlDataAdapter ds = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                            ds.Fill(dt);
                            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                            {
                                Name = dr["Name"].ToString();
                                Address = dr["Address"].ToString();
                                Picture = dr["Picture"].ToString();
                                Price = dr["Price"].ToString();
                            }
                            con.Close();
                            if (Request.Cookies["aa"] == null)
                            {
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = Name.ToString() + "," + Address.ToString() + "," + Picture.ToString() + "," + Price.ToString();
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Value = Request.Cookies["aa"].Value + "|" + Name.ToString() + "," + Address.ToString() + "," + Picture.ToString() + "," + Price.ToString();
                                Response.Cookies["aa"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide more info about your problem. From the code snippet you shared, I don't think the data is persisted to the database

Comment: @user3402754 im trying to restrict user from selecting duplicate elements for shopping. I am populating my list with the ids of the item. then im tranfering them to the hashset just to make sure that no duplicate id is present. dan i am fetching the data from database and inserting it into cookies. Every thing is going fine except this issue. On every click my list get refreshed and empty. I am not sure why

Comment: @user3402754 should i use postback check here ? actually im new to asp. :|

Answer (score 0):

If this is the whole onClick event function, you should create the lists outside the scope of the function. 
For example, create the lists in the Page_Load

Answer (score 0):

This could be about state management. The statelessness of http means you loose any form of state (eg. variables that are created during a request-response cycle) Try using session or any other state management technique to persist the list in between clicks.
`Session["venues"] = venues` to put the list in the session. And `var venues = (list<int>)Session["venues"]` to read the list from the session

Comment: if(Session["venue"] == null) {
Session["venue"] = venue; }
this will save only the first value. Issue will remain the same, as my list is not retaining its previous values

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by my self. I used static list to solve the issue. Thanks everyone!